# Escaped Characters in URI generated by call to URL.Action with jQuery Script

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, escaping, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following code as part of a jquery script to open a jqueryui dialog (the id value is hard-coded for testing purposes):

```
        open: function (event, ui) {

            $(this).load("@Url.Action("Edit", "Person",
                new
                {
                    id = Guid.Parse("28769371-7518-49db-a5ea-b9c62621a609"),
                    selectedPersonFor = Model.SelectedPersonFor,
                    selectedPersonForId = Model.SelectedPersonForId,
                    clientAccountId = Model.ClientAccountId
                })");
        },
```

The problem I have is that, even though my dialog opens, the controller action is never hit.

If I view the source in my browser the output produced is:

```
open: function (event, ui) {

            $(this).load("/Person/Edit/28769371-7518-49db-a5ea-b9c62621a609?selectedPersonFor=ClientAccount&amp;selectedPersonForId=2a2dd3b9-a73b-4afa-8237-5a4f37736f8a&amp;clientAccountId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
        },
```

I have found that if I hardcode the URI above into my script and replace the escaped ampersand (&) with a non-escaped ampersand (&) then my controller action gets hit.

I have tried adding a call to the replace method in my script to get rid of the escaped ampersand, but this does not help.  When I look at other URI's within the same page that are generated to call controller actions, *but not within a script*, I note that they have escaped ampersands within them.

There seems to be some difference in how the browser is processing the call to the controller action from the script as to how it is doing it from outside the script - and all related to the escaped ampersand.

Can someone direct me in how to overcome this problem?

Further info:

I have also tried passing the query parameters to the load function as follows:

```
open: function (event, ui) {

            $(this).load("@Url.Action("Edit", "Person")",
                {
                    id: @Guid.Parse("28769371-7518-49db-a5ea-b9c62621a609"),
                    selectedPersonFor: Model.SelectedPersonFor,
                    selectedPersonForId: Model.SelectedPersonForId,
                    clientAccountId: Model.ClientAccountId
                });
        },
```

However when I do it this way my dialog does not even open.

Edit:

In response to request to show route I provide the following (hopefully this is what was being requested):

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I'm just using the default routes provided with my asp.net mvc3 project.

Comment: it'll be easier to answer if you show your route

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Razor the `@` operator is used to HTML encode the output => `&` becomes `&amp;`. If you don't want this to happen you could use the `Html.Raw` helper:

```
var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Edit", "Person", new {
    id = Guid.Parse("28769371-7518-49db-a5ea-b9c62621a609"),
    selectedPersonFor = Model.SelectedPersonFor,
    selectedPersonForId = Model.SelectedPersonForId,
    clientAccountId = Model.ClientAccountId
}))';
$(this).load(url);
```

Now let's consider your second code snippet:

```
$(this).load("@Url.Action("Edit", "Person")", {
    id: @Guid.Parse("28769371-7518-49db-a5ea-b9c62621a609"),
    selectedPersonFor: Model.SelectedPersonFor,
    selectedPersonForId: Model.SelectedPersonForId,
    clientAccountId: Model.ClientAccountId
});
```

If you look at the rendered HTML you will see this:

```
$(this).load("@Url.Action("Edit", "Person")", {
    id: 28769371-7518-49db-a5ea-b9c62621a609,
    selectedPersonFor: Model.SelectedPersonFor,
    selectedPersonForId: Model.SelectedPersonForId,
    clientAccountId: Model.ClientAccountId
});
```

which obviously doesn't work because `Model.SelectedPersonForId` is probably not a valid javascript variable so your are getting a javascript error. Also `28769371-7518-49db-a5ea-b9c62621a609` is not a valid javascript expression as you haven't wrapped in in quotes.

If you want this to work make sure you generate proper contents:

```
$(this).load("/Person/Edit", {
    id: '@Guid.Parse("28769371-7518-49db-a5ea-b9c62621a609")',
    selectedPersonFor: '@Model.SelectedPersonFor',
    selectedPersonForId: '@Model.SelectedPersonForId',
    clientAccountId: '@Model.ClientAccountId'
});
```

Notice the `@` operator used before each server side variable and not only in front of the Guid. Also notice that the values are wrapped as javascript strings.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to point out the problems with my 2nd code snippet.  I've made the changes you suggested and now my dialog shows, but still my controller action is not hit.

Comment: @daveywc, what's the generated markup? Why is your controller action not hit? What do you see in the FireBug console? What is sent to the controller during the AJAX request? What does the server respond?

Comment: the generated markup is:   $(this).load("/Person/Edit",
                    {
                        id: '28769371-7518-49db-a5ea-b9c62621a609',
                        selectedPersonFor: 'ClientAccount',
                        selectedPersonForId: '2a2dd3b9-a73b-4afa-8237-5a4f37736f8a',
                        clientAccountId: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
                    });

Comment: will check your other suggestions later - but the generated markup looks fine, so I cannot understand why the controller action is not hit.

Comment: @daveywc, seems fine to me. Is your controller action accessible with the POST verb? When you use this overload of the .load method it sends a POST request? Maybe your controller action doesn't expect a POST request and it is not hitting the right action? Have you decorated your action with the `[HttpGet]` attribute by any chance? If you had, then this action allows only GET verbs which would explain why it is not hit. To use a GET verb you could either use the first suggestion or use the full `.ajax` method which allows you to specify the HTTP verb.

Comment: I managed to get it to work using the Html.Raw code that you provided above (I did have to edit your code to replace the colons with an equals sign when populating the url variable - could you please edit your answer accordingly).  The final piece of the puzzle was that my controller action was returning a partial view that did not have the jquery scripts defined.  Once I defined my scripts it all worked as expected.

Comment: So for the sake of clarity the resolution to my problem was to wrap the url with the call to Html.Raw.